# app to automatically print e-mails from iphone to a printer wirelessly

Tags: ios, email, printing

Right now I am using an email client to forward my emails to my printer from my computer. It's called thunderbird. Thunderbird however doesn't have a phone app. what i would like is the ability automatically print emails that are received in my inbox from gmail or outlook. How can I achieve this?

The mobile device I am using is an iphone. It will be running the latest OS for iphone7 and greater. The printer that I would use going forward would be any standard thermal receipt printer. The email address that will receive customer orders will be strictly maintained only to receive customer email orders so I don't mind if it prints every email.